# ajax question for auto suggestion and drop down

Tags: ajax

Please go here -- http://auspost.com.au/apps/postcode.html

when i type 314 an ajax call is fired ,when i type 5 after it then again another call is fired but when i delete the 5 then no call is fired but still showing the data.

How they are doing this ? Please help me as I am new to this concept

Comment: The way autocomplete works is if you type a string, then clip to have only a part of that string, it uses the old list and restricts within that list.  So if you type "123" then backspace to "12" it uses the old list with the new restriction.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery:

```
 $(function() {
      inputField = $('#inputfield');

      inputField.keyup(function() {
         if (inputField.val().length >= 3){
            // do you ajaxcall here
         }
         else {
           // do nothing - inputlength isn't at least three
         }
      });
   });
```

Though, it seems like Australia Post is just using the jQuery UI autocomplete with minChars 3. Read about jQuery ui autocomplete here http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete.

You can also try this post: jQuery UI Autocomplete and Caching Query Results http://developwithstyle.com/articles/2010/05/14/jquery-ui-autocomplete-is-it-any-good.html

Actually you'll find a nice guide at http://deathofagremmie.com/2010/04/03/jquery-ui-autocomplete-widget-caching/ that probably does what you want.

Comment: +1 but should be `inputField.val().length >= 3` or alternatively `> 2` ;)

Comment: The AJAX call may or may not be fired when the length is 3. The OP is asking how they implement hysteresis.

Comment: I've corrected it and given a ref. to Autocomplete, since thats what Australian Post is using.

Comment: And how they store the data from previous callbacks

Comment: i understand that but it seems that they are storing the data locally somewhere ,next time when i delete  anumber or add the same it does not fire but instead shows from memory

Comment: Maybe they're using local browser databases, implemented in HTML5. Anybody with Google chrome, check it please

Comment: The last url gives you how to implement a basic cache for your results.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like they're storing data using JQuery $.data() function.
That's what I found in their webapps.js file:

```
var a=$(this);$(a).data("hintText","Enter suburb or postcode");
if($(a).attr("value")==""){$(a).val($(a).data("hintText")).addClass("ac_hint")}$(a).focusin(function(){
if($(a).val()==$(this).data("hintText")){$(a).val("");$(a).removeClass("ac_hint")}}).focusout(function(){
if($.trim($(a).val())==""){$(a).val($(a).data("hintText"));$(a).addClass("ac_hint")}})})}
//...
```

Check the file yourself if you want the details.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is to see whether the new value is a prefix of the previous value. After a bit of playing around, I think it may just cache a certain number of fetched results. But that's just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

The relevant code is in [webapp.js](http://static.auspost.com.au/scripts/webapps.js)

Autocompletion is being invoked in mostly the normal way but the autocomplete function is later extended in order to perform additional processing

```
function init_apps_autocomplete() {
    $(".fn_autocomplete").each(function () {var a = 207;if ($(this).parents("#module_iWantTo").length > 0 || $(this).parents("#modal_iWantTo").length > 0) {a = 182;}$(this).autocomplete(API_AUTOCOMPLETE, {minChars: 3, width: a, matchContains: false, autoFill: false, captureUsage: true, formatItem: function (d, c, b) {return d[2] + (" " + d[3] + " " + d[1]);}, formatMatch: function (d, c, b) {return d[2] + (" " + d[1]);}, formatResult: function (b) {return b[2] + (" " + b[1]);}, onSelection: function () {$(".fn_autocomplete").parents("form").find("select option:first").attr("selected", true);}, max: 10});});
    ...
}
```

It is achieving caching by extending the autocomplete function like so

```
(function (a) {a.fn.extend({autocomplete: function (b, c) {.....}});}(jQuery));
```

Within this `jQuery.fn.extend()` a separate `jQuery.extend()` is then executed to create a new Autocompleter object within jQuery. This object contains a lot of additional processing including some cache management which is more than likely what you're looking for.

The code has been minified to the point where it is difficult to follow and I haven't worked out exactly what way this cache process is carried out but hopefully this will give you a start.